# how does Keras ImageDataGenerator standardize data?

Tags: neural-networks, standardization, keras

If I understand correctly the ImageDataGenerator class is a generator and returns batches of images when called, but what I don't seem to understand is:

- featurewise_center
- featurewise_std_normalization

The documentation says:

- featurewise_center: Boolean. Set input mean to 0 over the dataset, feature-wise.
- featurewise_std_normalization: Boolean. Divide inputs by std of the dataset, feature-wise.

How can you set mean to 0 over entire dataset when you have only a batch of images at any given time? and same for normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, normally you would not be able to tell these from a single batch of loaded samples.

This is why before you use `ImageDataGenerator` for generating batches, you need to fit it to your data, to calculate the statistics necessary for normalization.

Here is an example from [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)

# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, epochs=epochs)
```